# mySQL: How to display a string upon encountering a specific string in a column using CASE?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want to accomplish is that, when I encounter the string Rotterdam, I want to replace it with N/A
I was able to do it using IF command, can someone tell me why my CASE command is giving error?

Code:
If

```
SELECT id,if(name like 'rotterdam','N/A',name)
   ,
    COUNTRYCODE,
    DISTRICT,
    POPULATION
    
FROM city
LIMIT 10;
```

Case (incorrect)

```
SELECT id,/* if(name like 'rotterdam','N/A',name) */
   CASE
        WHEN name LIKE 'ROTTERDAM' THEN 'N/A'
        ELSE SELECT name
    END,
    COUNTRYCODE,
    DISTRICT,
    POPULATION
    
FROM city
LIMIT 10;
```

The table:
[Table image][image: 1]

My approach: [using case command][image: 2]   (you can see the error here)

[using if command (works)][image: 3]

Desired Output: [you can see N/A in the second column][image: 4]

Comment: I also tried CASE ...... THEN SELECT 'N/A' ; didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a second `select`:

```
(CASE WHEN name LIKE 'ROTTERDAM' THEN 'N/A'
      ELSE name
 END)
```

You *could* use `SELECT`, but it would be silly and require a subquery:

```
(CASE WHEN name LIKE 'ROTTERDAM' THEN 'N/A'
      ELSE (SELECT name)
 END)
```

Note that the `SELECT` (without parentheses) would not work with `IF()` either.

Comment: Got it, so basically the second SELECT cmd in the ELSE was causing the problem, right?

Comment: @RealSlimShady . . . Yes, the `SELECT` was causing the problem.